# How to pass single parameter, multiple parameter or null to a report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

I am trying to create a report from a query that returns a list of transactions which contains the following:
`Trans_Id`, `Trans_Type`, `date`, `amount`, `status`, `client`

The query would be simply the following:

```
Select  Trans_Id, Trans_Type, date, amount, status, client
from table.
```

What I want to do is to add all the columns as parameters for the report, allowing the user to fill one parameter or more than one parameter and based on that will return the data or fill nothing so it will return everything.
It's like activating a WHERE condition if a parameter is filled otherwise return everything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be a function which uses dynamic SQL to assemble a SELECT statement based on the populated paramaters. However that is probably overkill for the simple query you post.

This solution tests whether each parameter is null or compares it to the pertinent column:

```
Select Trans_Id, Trans_Type, date, amount, status, client 
from your_table yt
where ( :p_Trans_Id is null or :p_Trans_Id = yt.Trans_Id ) 
and ( :p_Trans_Type is null or :p_Trans_Type = yt.Trans_Type ) 
and ( :p_date is null or :p_date = yt.date ) 
and ( :p_amount is null or :p_amount = yt.amount ) 
and ( :p_status is null or :p_status = yt.status ) 
and ( :p_client is null or :p_client = yt.client )
/
```

This is a recognised technique, but it can be difficult to tune such a query. So be sure to test it thoroughly with realistic volumes of data.

---

Note: parameter syntax varies depending on the client used to call the statement.